# VSCode: auto-indent Java code on paste

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out how to make VSCode auto-indent Java code on paste. I have `"editor.formatOnPaste": true` in settings Java Extension Pack installed. Other code (say, JSON) gets auto-indented on paste without any further actions needed. Moreover, if I first paste Java code and then run `Reindent Lines` from command palette, Java code gets correctly indented. Problem is with doing so automatically. Any ideas?